# synchronize two github and google code repositories

Tags: git, svn, github, google-code

Scenario:
There is an original svn (google code) repository that is not mine.
http://asterisk-chan-dongle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
I want to keep my own copy of that repo on my google code account. However my copy will have some changes made by me.
So I do:
svn checkout http://asterisk-chan-dongle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ asterisk-chan-dongle-read-only
I make my changes. And now:
How do I upload it to google code?
How do I synchronize my google code repo with the original one preserving my changes , and is it possible to do it without gcreating a local copy on my harddrive?

How to solve the same problem with two github repos?

Answer (score 0):

To do this with Subversion, you will need your own repository. Then treat the "original" as a [vendor branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html). Export a copy of the original repository's code, commit to your own. Then check out a copy from your repository, make your changes, commit, and so on.

You will have to maintain this vendor branch regularly if the original source is changing.

The only way to get the changes upstream to the original repository is to send the maintainer(s) of that repository a patch and hope they accept it.

You'll have to do do pretty much the same thing with git, unless Google Code has a git interface that doesn't appear on that project's page. The process is much easier when using a project that's hosted on Github, however. At Github, you'll just fork the original repository, make changes in yours, and then submit a pull request to the original (which is similar to the patch submission w/ Subversion, but more streamlined). You'll also need to occasionally pull changes from the upstream repository, but again that's more streamlined than it is with Subversion.